# AppFabric caching session state : count session

Tags: session, count, session-state, appfabric

I think about using AppFabric as a solution for session state.

But How do I know the current number of session on AppFabric cache ?

Comment: the only way I found for the moment is counting on each webserver and centralize in another interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try GetObjectsInRegion or GetObjectsByTag. It's the only way I could find to do this. Using regions has penalties though. As far as I'm aware, data cached within a region would reside on a single cache host so you'd lose some of the high availability failover tolerance of AppFabric.